# Is there a way to extract Picture OLEObjects from a table?

Tags: vba, ms-access

This is a follow up to this question:
[Is there a way to extract AutoCAD Drawings and Pictures from an OLE Object field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56705196/is-there-a-way-to-extract-autocad-drawings-and-pictures-from-an-oleobject-field/56707551)

So the question remains, how would I go about retrieving the images stored in a *Picture* OLEObject? If anyone has succeeded in this and could shed some light I would really appreciate it. As I said in my previous post I've searched extensively for this and even tried several times on my own but I can't seem to get anywhere.

Thanks in advance, Rafael.

Edit to include Image. The message is what appears upon double-click. The OLE Object in question shows up if inserted into a Bound Object Frame in a Form.

Edit2: These *Picture* Objects can be recreated by taking a printscreen or a Snip (using the Snipping Tool on Windows) and pasting with CTRL+V on an OLE Object Field in a Table or a Bound Object Frame in a Form.

[image]

Comment: So what do you mean by 'Picture' - what image format? Why did Lebans code fail? Keep searching. Maybe here https://officeaccelerators.wordpress.com/2014/11/23/extract-ole-objects-from-access-to-disk/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract Blob data from Access via vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29616371/extract-blob-data-from-access-via-vbscript)

Comment: @June7 I updated the post with an image refering the _Picture_ I'm talking about. Not sure this falls under the category of BLOB...

Comment: I can get BLOB code to run and create a file but the result is not recognized by any image viewer I have. Lebans shows Picture object in sample data so I tried it but get 'Subscript out of range' error and that is running his sample db as is. The other objects export but I can't view snp file.

Comment: I did right click on the OLEObject control on form then pasted to MSPaint. So maybe https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/260955-how-do-i-save-bitmap-image-clipboard-bmp-file.html

Comment: Copying and pasting to MSPaint works, I'll take a look at that to try and automate it. Thanks a lot! Consider posting this as your answer.