# Is there any way to leave a "front-end" in MS Access when a table exceeds 2GB?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, client, filesize, ole

There appears to be no solution to continuing to use a "front-end" (form) in MS Access once the single table exceeds 2GB, regardless of where the data resides.  Further, since there is no way to query-SPAN linked tables in multiple Access databases, there is no solution there either.  Am I correct?

MS Access 2016 on Win10, & SQL Server 2014 on Server 2012, tons of storage & memory everywhere.

Because I have used OLE "pictures", the table has exceeded the 2GB limit in Access.  I exported the table to SQL Server 2014 and linked to it, then changed the properties of the form (in Access) to attach to it.  It seems to work fine except that the end of the table cannot be accessed using the end of table control, or a 'find' for data I know is in a specific field near the end of the table, so it appears that moving my data to SQL Server is pointless.

The error I get when jumping or finding is:

> The query cannot be completed.  Either the size of the query result is larger than the maximum size of a database (2 GB), or there is not enough temporary storage space on the disk to store the query result.'

There are vbscript blocks in use, but the failure comes when using Access-native controls.

If I'm doing something wrong, please advise.
As stated, I tried "spanning" table segments, but there doesn't seem to be a way to query ALL records from both tables, or a way to construct a query to mask the origin of fields, or very likely any benefit as it would likely produce the same "exceeds 2GB" error as SQL did above.

I would consider exporting the OLE "pictures" to files, and reading them back into the form, record by record when viewing, but there are no functions in MS Access that support this, or any of the other functions I'd need to do it going forward. (write file from form.OLE, etc.)

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you fetching many former OLE-Fields (binary bloon on Sql Server)? If your recordset data exceeds 2GB the x86 app crashes as every x86 app can only handle max memory of 2GB. Reduce size by fetching path to images or PK of binary blob table and fetch the images one by one when needed.

Comment: How to export from OLEObject field is topic of numerous threads. For a start, review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56739104/is-there-a-way-to-extract-picture-oleobjects-from-a-table?noredirect=1#comment100091613_56739104