# Access Database using linked tables maximum size

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc

I created an *.mdb file (Access 2002 - 2003 file format) and I added in Access (from External Data tab - Excel) an ODBC DataBase
(that I configured in ODBC DataSource Administrator 32-bit to point to a MySQL database server) using "Link to the datasource by creating a linked table".

I know that an Access file can be max. 2 GB.

Question:

1. In this situation with the linked tables, can I bypass the Access maximum threshold?
2. What will be the max. threshold, that from Access or from MySQL server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted, since Access is not the database anymore, then such limits don't exist.

EVEN if you bind the form directly to a linked table, the limit does not exist.

So, here is a form based on a linked table, and the linked table has 10 million rows, (and SQL server shows that the ONE table is more then 2 gigs in size.

Note how the speed is also instant, and the form is bound DIRECTLY to that linked table with 10 million rows. There are no views, no stored procedures or anything. Just a simple linked table is used here.

Note how the form with the "filter" opens instant, and does so without any special code, but a "common" used "where" clause of the open form command.

the code behind the button is this:

```
Private Sub Command5_Click()

   DoCmd.OpenForm "frmBigHistory", , , "id = " & Text2
      
   
End Sub
```

Now, if I open that form bound to the table without a filter?

It loads instant, but if I decide to "move to" the last reocrd, then a BIG dealy occures, but the form (in about 25 seconds) does and will load the whole data set.

so, here is this in effect
(the form starts out with the WHOLE 10 million data set loaded, and I navigate back to 1st record, then last.

Then I show the same form (with 10 million rows) being launched with a filter - and Access then ONLY pulls the ONE record from SQL server with above code example.

[image]

So, in this example, the database is more then 2 gigs (it is about 7 gigs in size).

And that one table is over 2 gigs in size.

Answer (score 3):

Since the linked data is not stored in Access, this limit does not apply.

There are, however, other limits as listed in [Access specifications](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/access-specifications-0cf3c66f-9cf2-4e32-9568-98c1025bb47c). E.g. number of fields in a table (255) or the number of columns and bytes per rows returned in a query.

Comment: Note that there are situations where one or multiple tables are fully cached in the Access database, and when this exceeds 2GB you will encounter problems. While this answer is generally true, it's still a bad idea to use Access with huge databases.

Comment: @ErikA. This sounds very surprising to me. What are these situations?

Comment: Off the top of my head at least the following: forms bound to snapshot-type recordsets, opening tables and pressing the _last_ button ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56780159/7296893)), transactional queries that can't be translated to SQL server (e.g. Access-style merge queries through the GUI). My personal approach is to minimize the usage of huge tables to either VBA and ADODB or filtered passthrough queries that will not return >1GB of data, and to make sure compact on close is on.

Comment: The poor user who has to scroll through 1 GB of data! :-( I think that this can be avoided. 1) the DB being that big does not mean that a single table is that big. 2) don't present that much data to the user (e.g. use filters, paging...). 3) use stored procedures to process huge amounts of data. This will be much faster than Access (non-passthrough) queries or VBA code anyway.

Comment: how Access works, or a c++ or c# or vb.net program to such large databases? Tjhey are ALL the same, and in fact perform the same. And in Access there not any real difference then say using c++ or c# to pull data from SQL server. If one attempts to pull 2 gig of data in one "go", then it may well give rise to a issue. However, in my answer below, I am able to "navigate" to the end of a 10 million row table - one that SQL server shows is about 3 gigs in size. And as my answer shows below - I am AM able to pull the whole big table into that form - but not recommended!!!

Answer (score -2):

The maximum file size of an Access (*.mdb) file is 2 GB. Linking tables to a MySQL database does not change this limit. The maximum size of a MySQL database depends on its configuration, but a linked table in Access will still be limited to 2 GB. If you're dealing with a large amount of data, it's recommended to split the database into smaller databases or consider using a more robust database management system like Microsoft SQL Server or MySQL.

Comment: MS Access will not know, nor care about the table size for a linked table, this answer is not correct.

Comment: The other answer is correct, no need to repeat it.

Comment: Actually, yes, linking to a database like SQL or MySQL? You most certainly do not have the 2 gig limit - even if the ONE table is greater then 2 gigs - the screen shots in my above answer shows a form that loaded 10 million rows. while 10 million rows of data is "small" these days, that one table is > 2 gigs in size. And note how fast Access responds to open that form with a simple "where" clause in VBA. Note that the form is bound DIRECTLY to the table (no views, no stored procedure or anything at all - but JUST a linked table). there is no perceptible delay at all when opening that form.